# How do I update .csdef for Azure Cloud Service (Extended Support) when deploying via PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-services

I'm migrating from cloud services classic to cloud services extended support and I'm also moving to deploy with a mixture of yml and powershell.

The documentation [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/new-azcloudservice?view=azps-11.1.0) mentions around using New-AzureCloudService for creating and updating the service but when I try to call it for the update I get an error saying the cloud service already exists hence why I've tried to get the cloud service first and if found, update they values but I can't seem to update the definition file as no property exists.

Here is the snippet of code I'm using

```
$cloudService = Get-AzCloudService -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -CloudServiceName $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 if ($cloudService) {
      $cloudService.packageUrl = $cspkgUrl
      $cloudService.Configuration = Get-Content "$buildDirectory/ServiceConfiguration.Dev.cscfg"
     
      $cloudService | Update-AzCloudService
 } else {
     New-AzCloudService `
         -Name $name `
         -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
         -Location "$location" `
         -ConfigurationFile "$buildDirectory/ServiceConfiguration*.cscfg" `
         -DefinitionFile "$buildDirectory/ServiceDefinition.csdef" `
         -packageUrl $cspkgUrl
 }
```

I'm using Az v11.1.0 and Az.CloudService v2.0.0

I'm expecting to be able to set the definition file path or url when updating the cloud service but I can't seem to workout how.

Slightly unrelated but the cloud service is triggered via a service bus so I could delete the cloud service and redeploy the entire service but I feel this is overcomplicating it and I should just be able to update the csdef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I update .csdef for Azure Cloud Service (Extended Support) when deploying via PowerShell: -

After a workaround on your requirement, the solution I found is you have to modify the `.csdef` or `.csdef` files manually and then point it to the updated package file with the `Update-AzCloudService` command. It means that you can only modify the `packageurl` as you already did in your code. There is no possibility of modifying the `.csdef` or `.cscfg` files directly with the `Update-AzCloudService` command.

As mentioned above, I modified `.csdef` file and uploaded it to the storage account. Once it's done, I was obtaining the updated package URL from storage account as shown below.

```
$StartTime = Get-Date  
$EndTime = $tokenStartTime.AddYears(2) 
$acccontext = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName xx -Name xxx 
$blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container  xxx -Blob xxx.cspkg -Context  $acccontext.Context 
$Token = New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Container xxx -Blob xx.cspkg -Permission rwd -StartTime  $StartTime -ExpiryTime  $EndTime -Context  $acccontext.Context 
$Url = $blob.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + $Token
```

[image]

*Note*: After retrieving the URL in the above given manner, use your existed code to update the cloud service.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/new-azcloudservice?view=azps-11.1.0) for better understanding on create/update a cloud service with PowerShell.